# Maximum sizes of independent sets in (non-uniform) hypergraphs

Tags: pr.probability, hypergraph, extremal-combinatorics

It is a very well understood problem to compute the size of the maximum  independent set in a uniform hypergraph (in terms of extra conditions).

My question is the following: what is known for hypergraphs that are not uniform? I know the very elementary probabilistic proof by Spencer in his 1972 paper "[Turán's theorem for k-graphs](https://www.rand.org/pubs/papers/P4648-1.html)" (which uses 1st moment method) but I do not know if there is some later work in which the method is refined somehow (also, maybe using extra assumptions on the hypergraph).

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to do. As stated, the only thing that one can say is that there is a huge literature about independent sets in hypergraphs, and what you want is somewhere in that literature.

Comment: Thanks: I want to know what is known whenever we have very weak conditions on our hypergraph. Spencer's result is a very basic one, which needs essentially nothing to our hypergraph, but my impression is that one could improve it with some more sofisticated probabilistic argument.